# .NET Core Benchmarking without database

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, benchmarking

I'm looking for an effective way to benchmark my server endpoints & business logic.
The problem I encounter is when I want to avoid accessing the database in terms of reading and writing to it when i benchmark my methods. I have recently been using the `NSubstitute` library for unit testing to mock database\storage methods. I was wondering if I could use something similar in my benchmarking classes - something like this:

**Main program**

```
public static async Task Benchmark()
 {
   BenchmarkRunner.Run<Logins>();          
 }
```

**Logins Class**

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[Orderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
public class Logins
{
    private const string UserId = "60c9d";
    private const string Email = "example@main.club";

    [Benchmark]
    public async Task LoginWithEmail()
    {
       // This is my login method 
        await UserLoginManager.Instance.LoginWithEmail(Email, Password);
    }
}
```

LoginWithEmail method contains a call for db which i would like to ignore or substitute/Mock. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: What would be the point of benchmarking a method while excluding the part that, more likely or not, is its actual bottleneck? Benchmarking the parts that aren't bottlenecks to optimize those is a waste of effort. If you have reason to suspect your logic without the database might take significant time, it pays to split off that logic so you can benchmark and test it separately. If you already have effective test methods that do this (regardless of how they accomplish it) you can just benchmark those directly. (Most testing frameworks already include things like execution time for tests).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Any method I want to banchmark requires an entire state behind it. This is a complex system- I want to avoid calculating and setting up the state for each method call.